# Making decision randomly on Ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I need to write code that makes a choice between several options based on randomly generated number.

For example, the following (Ruby 1.9.3) code determines which of 3 bins the user will win based on a rand() result and is what I'd like to achieve:

```
n = 3
rnd1 = rand()
if (0 <= rnd1) and (rnd1 < 1 * 1.0 / n)
  puts "Won first bin"
elsif (1 * 1.0 / n <= rnd1) and (rnd1 <= 2 * 1.0 / n)
  puts "Won second bin)
else
  puts "Won third bin"
end
```

However, this code is ugly and I'm certain not efficient either.
I'd appreciate any answer optimizing my code, giving a better code sample or referring me to a gem that does such a thing (if one exists).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest Ruby expression of this might be the `Array#sample` method:

```
[ 'Bin 1', 'Bin 2', 'Bin 3' ].sample
# => e.g. 'Bin 3'
```

It has additional syntax, for selecting more than one item at a time.

It does not provide a mechanism for weighted selections. It does not accept input of pre-calculated random number, if you need a certain random source. You are not asking these questions, but it is clear your example code is not your end goal.

Comment: The definitive answer ;)

Comment: Thank you. Using an array as a "bin counter" (pun intended) didn't even cross my mind but it's excellent idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`Kernel#rand`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) takes an optional argument to specify a range or a maximum value:

```
case rand(1..3)
when 1
  puts "Won first bin"
when 2
  puts "Won second bin"
when 3
  puts "Won third bin"
end
```